# Google Analytics Audience as Entry Source in Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, google-analytics, entry-criteria

The below Journey has a GA Entry source which is refreshing the data on a daily basis.

[image]

I wanted to know whether the new data is overwriting the existing records or is appending to the existing records to the Data Extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is the overwritten function.